# Serializing std::multiplies using Boost

Tags: c++, boost-serialization

I am trying to serialize the following user-defined object:

```
ConcatConstMapping<std::multiplies<double> >* obj;
```

Boost shows me the following error:

```
> /usr/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:118:9: error: ‘struct
> std::multiplies<double>’ has no member named ‘serialize’
```

This is how class `ConcatConstMapping` looks like:

```
template<class Operator>
class ConcatConstMapping: public ConstMapping
{
protected:

    typedef std::pair<Dimension, Argument::const_iterator> DimIteratorPair;
    typedef std::list<ConstMapping*> MappingSet;
    MappingSet            mappings;
    ConstMapping*         refMapping;

    bool                  continueOutOfRange;
    Argument::mapped_type oorValue;

    Operator op;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & archive, const unsigned int version)
    {
        archive & mappings;
        archive & refMapping;
        archive & continueOutOfRange;
        archive & oorValue;
        archive & op;
    }
};
```

Edit: The error is gone when I comment line `archive & op;`. But I fill I need to add that line too for serialization.

Answer (score 0):

For custom classes, you will need to declare the `serialize` function yourself, either as part of the class or as a free function, as explained in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#primitiveoperators).

```
template<class Archive>
inline void serialize(
    Archive & ar, 
    my_class & t, 
    const unsigned int file_version
) {
    // For example:
    ar & t.member_one;
    ar & t.member_two;
    ....
}
```

Comment: I already know that! how can I do this for std::multiplies struct ? Your answer seems to be general.

Comment: @ManiAm Key phrase is "free function". That `my_class` from the example quoted by Philipp should be replaced by std::multiplies. In fact, the passage in the documentation that the quoted example is in calls out specifically the STL as a use-case for the free function approach, since you can't add methods to them.

Comment: Now after looking closer, I'm not sure if you actually can serialize this, since it seems that ``std::multiplies`` doesn't store any data.

Comment: @PhilippLudwig but why boost is throwing me an error ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why would you like to serialize `multiplies` since, it doesnt store any data... so there is nothing to serialize. To satisfy the compiler, this should do:

```
template<class Archive>
inline void serialize(
    Archive & ar, 
    std::multiplies<double> & t, 
    const unsigned int file_version
) { }
```

If you provide this, the compiler will pick up a matching function... which does nothing.

I guess you could futher template this for `multiplies<T>`.

`multipilies` does not have a state, it's merely a functor wrapper around `lhs*rhs`. I'd advise you to reconsider your design to avoid serialization at all, rather than working around the error by serializing nothing.

Comment: thanks! I edited my code to show the class ConcatConstMapping content. It might help in figuring out why Boost is showing me error.